# Dynamic processing of string field based on user IP

Tags: entities

I am a relative newbie looking for guidance on how to best tackle a requirement within the Drupal 7 realm. I have an entity defined with a field containing the URL for an external resource and would like to be able to manipulate the URL string programmatically before rendering the field as a hypertext link within a view. I thought about storing the alternate URLs in the database but the format is subject to change so the dynamic approach is more attractive since it would only involve a single edit. I need to first check the $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] to determine whether or not to execute this code because if the user is requesting the resource from a location off site then a proxy link must be generated for licensing purposes. What approach would make the most sense for this use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the data in the cleanest way possible and then use something like [Custom Formatters](http://drupal.org/project/custom_formatters)
or a custom module to modify the presentation of the stored data.

As for using $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] I feel that I need more data on how and where this will be used.  Have you considered using the permissions or roles built into Drupal?

You would likely need to place this in a preprocess function to conditionally call it for a specific IP address.

For example.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_node().
 */
function hook_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
    //Obviously a real IP is required above for correct syntax.
    if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) {
        //Next you can edit the output of any field you want if your remote address matches.
        $variables['field_myfield'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 'Something Modified Here';
    }
}
```

Comment: edited question to clarify the usage of  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']